# SASS extend/share/inherit specific properties from parent to child or vice versa

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible to extend/share selected/specific properties to the child from parent for e.g. without creating a variable?

```
.main-container {
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 20px;

     ul {
          padding:$parentPadding();
          margin: 0;
     }          

 }
```

or vice versa

Comment: Sass has no concept of inheriting values like that.  You must use variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `.main-container { ul {` will be rendered as `.main-container ul {` , once the parent element for `ul` will be `.main-container` you can achieve what you want by using a purely CSS solution: `inherit`

```
ul{
  padding: inherit; //Will inherit the padding value of the parent element
}
```