# SCSS Dynamically assign margin based on another element

Tags: css, sass

I would rather not hard code a pixel value for my `margin-left` on one of my elements:

```
.my_element {
  margin-left: 75px;
}
```

What I would like to do, is make that `margin-left` be equal to the width of another element `+ 20px`.

```
.other_element {
  width: auto;
}

.my_element {
  margin-left: [somehow-reference-other-element-width];
}
```

I know if I had a static width, I could use `.scss` variables (`$myWidth: 75px;`) and set it to both, but I think I'd rather use `auto`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS extend/share/inherit specific properties from parent to child or visa vera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544361/sass-extend-share-inherit-specific-properties-from-parent-to-child-or-visa-vera)

Comment: Not really. But very similar. I want to not only get the property from a parent, but manipulate it. Not just inherit.

Comment: The answer is still the same, Sass has no functionality like that.

Answer (score 0):

`width: auto` fills the parent container after accounting for margin and border. I'm assuming `.other_element` is child of another container that will have to have some static width, otherwise it would fill the entire window width. If so, you could reference that parent width via scss variable and subtract off any margin and border of the child element.

Something like the following: (here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVRM8/1/))

```
$parent_width: 150px;
$other_margin: 20px;
$other_border: 5px;

.some_parent {
    width: $parent_width;
}

.other_element {
    width: auto;
    // optional margin and border
    margin: $other_margin;
    border: $other_border;
}

.my_element {
    margin-left: $parent_width - $other_margin - $other_border + 20;
}
```

It's tough to visualize what you are looking for, but this should work with percentages, ems, or whatever as well if you are making a responsive design.

Comment: The problem with this though, is that I have to set a defined width on the parent. I just wanted to know if it was possible to somehow retrieve the width from an element, and set the width of another based on it. But I suppose jQuery would be the only answer for that unfortunately.

Comment: As you are looking for dynamic (at runtime) values, a static SCSS stylesheet will not be able to do what you are looking for. You'll have to use some javascript.

Comment: I realize this now, I suppose I was hoping there was some CSS value that the browser would interpret and do it for me. But I understand it's not possible without some JS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same query, where I needed to make sure margin-left of sibling element is equal to the width of sibling1. In SCSS, there is no mechanism as such.

So, using JavaScript I did it.

```
 /** 4.--- JS Code to give width --- */
  const authorFirstName = document.querySelector(
    '.author-details-global .field--name-field-user-first-name',
  );
  const authorLastName = document.querySelector(
    '.author-details-global .field--name-field-user-last-name',
  );

  const authorFirstWidth = authorFirstName.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  console.log('**************');
  console.log(`${authorFirstWidth + 3}px`);
  authorLastName.style.marginLeft = `${authorFirstWidth + 3}px`;
```

You may use your selectors and use the same method to get the desired results